# How can I get the materials required for crafting TNT easily?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I would like to craft TNT, but I am having trouble getting the materials needed. How can I get the 5 gunpowder and 5 sand needed to craft TNT?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you near a river or desert sand should be easy to get. Just make sure you use a shovel. Gunpowder is the harder part, but fortunately there are several ways to get it:

- If you manage to find a desert temple looting it can sometimes give you all the TNT and gunpowder you need! Just make sure you dig below the treasure room and DON'T step on the pressure plate.
- Creepers drop from 0-2 gunpowder. Not a lot but if you make a mob farm you should get it at an adequate speed.
- If you don't know how to make a mob farm then you can spend a few nights up killing creepers. If you have and iron sword or greater you can rush the creeper (rapidly attacking them). If you have wooden or stone sword put in a few hits then back away then attack again.

These are the best ways to get gunpowder and TNT. Hope this helped!

Comment: If you know how to make a mob farm - or just find a tutorial - that's the most efficient way. Note: tested&true designs for Bedrock Edition. Clickbait with non-unctional crap is abundant, also Java farms are unlikely to work.